# Prevent my clients from giving or selling my software using a LGPLv3 library to others

Tags: licensing, lgpl

I am  developing a commercial closed software using Qt which is under LGPLv3.

May I prevent my clients from giving copies to other people?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If it were a GPL app, you wouldn't be able to do this, but LGPL has an important difference: the viral licensing property doesn't affect your project's code *if you dynamically link to it.*  So as long as all the QT code is in its own DLLs, rather than compiled directly into your project, you'll be fine.